# Joining a list of characters into a list of words

Tags: python, string, list, join, cpu-word

I want to join a string. I tried using `.join` and it works for displaying that string as a whole but not in the next step I want to use it in:

```
Packet = "w","a","l","k"," ","1","2"," ","1","0"
FullPacket = "".join(Packet)
print(FullPacket)
```

Output:

```
walk 12 10
```

After that I want to compare certain words included in the whole packet, but right now when I do:

```
print(len(FullPacket)) it shows me the amount of characters in the string thus
print(FullPacket[0])  will only display the first letter
```

And I understand that happens because that string is not a bunch of words, it's a bunch of characters joined together. Is there any way to join those letters into words, so they count as whole words instead of letters like they do now?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve that, the easier is to  :

1. group all the chars as you did,
2. then split on spaces, to get words

```
packet = "w", "a", "l", "k", " ", "1", "2", " ", "1", "0"

full_packet = "".join(packet)
print(full_packet)  # walk 12 10

words_packet = full_packet.split()  # no argument means any amount of space
print(words_packet)  # ['walk', '12', '10']
print(len(words_packet))  # 3
print(words_packet[0])  # walk
```

---

ps: `python` naming convention is [`snake_case` (lowercase with underscores)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of,

```
FullPacket = "".join(Packet)
```

try,

```
FullPacket = "".join(Packet).split(" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try FullPacker.split()

Answer (score -1):

You can also do as the following:

```
packet = "w", "a", "l", "k", " ", "1", "2", " ", "1", "0"
''.join(list(packet))
```